# Повысит ли производительность react/redux приложения копирование части стора редакса в локальный стейт компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Всем привет, когда мне нужно изменить какую-то часть redux стора, я копирую его в стейт компонента, изменяю его локально, используя setState, а затем одним экшеном отправляю его обратно в стор, это выглядит примерно так:

```
export class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: this.props.user,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.user.name}
          onChange={this.changeUserName}
        />
        <button onClick={this.saveUser}>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  userNameChange = ({target}) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      user: {
        ...prevState.user,
        name: target.value,
      },
    }));
  }

  saveUser = () => {
    const {
      userActions,
    } = this.props;

    const {
      user,
    } = this.state;

    userActions.save(user);
  }
}

const mapStateToUserProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

const mapDispatchToUserProps = (dispatch) => ({
  userActions: bindActionCreators(UserActions, dispatch),
})

export const UserContainer = connect(mapStateToUserProps, mapDispatchToUserProps)(User);
```

Мне кажется, что это позволит избавиться от какой-то доли вызова селекторов (mapStateToProps) и повысит производительность приложения, с другой стороны это противоречит концепциям одного источника правды и изменения данных только в редьюссерах. Я начинал замечать незначительные проблемы этого решения, когда пытался реализовать "оптимистичный интерфейс". Что вы думаете по этому поводу? Выигрыш в производительности не стоит тех проблем, которые могут возникнуть?

Comment: Кажется, что у Вас есть ответ на Ваш вопрос: *это противоречит концепциям одного источника правды и изменения данных только в редьюссерах*. Относительно выигрыша в производительности - спорный вопрос, не думаю, что имеется значительный прирост.

Answer (score 0):

если честно, в Вашем случае я не вижу смысла копировать что либо в `state` компонента. судя по коду, проще повесить `ref` на `input` для получения значения в методе `saveUser`. **Это потому, что** изменения в поле `input` с помощью метода `onChange` ни на что не влияют, а лишняя перерисовка будет срабатывать каждый раз.